# How to integrate $\int_0^\infty {\theta^{-(\alpha+1)}}*e^{-\frac{\beta}{\theta}}d\theta$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, chain-rule

I think this is a reverse product rule but I could not figure out how to reverse this.

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\theta^{-(\alpha+1)}}*e^{-\frac{\beta}{\theta}}d\theta$$

I pulled out the constants but then got stuck here:
$$\frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_0^\infty {\theta^{-(\alpha+1)}}*e^{-\frac{\beta}{\theta}}d\theta$$

$\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants while $\Gamma$ is a function.

Comment: You want "integration by parts".

Comment: $\Gamma(\alpha)$ is also a constant  So this is really just the interval $\int_0^\infty x^{a}e^{-b/x}dx$ modulo a constant.

Comment: yea gamma only depends on alpha, that's why i pulled it out. i'm going to try integration by parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change of variable $\;u:=\dfrac {\beta}{\theta}\;$ should help much here giving  $\;\theta:=\dfrac {\beta}u,\;d\theta=-\dfrac{\beta}{u^2}du\;$ and :

\begin{align} I(\alpha,\beta)&:=\dfrac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_0^{\infty}
{\theta^{-(\alpha+1)}}\;e^{-\large{\frac{\beta}{\theta}}}d\theta\\
&=\dfrac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_{\infty}^0
\left(\frac {\beta}u\right)^{-(\alpha+1)}\;e^{-u}\frac {-\beta}{u^2}\,du\\
&=\dfrac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_0^{\infty}
\beta\left(\frac{u}{\beta}\right)^{\alpha+1}\;e^{-u}\frac 1{u^2}\,du\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_0^{\infty} u^{\alpha-1}\;e^{-u}\,du\\
&=\dfrac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\Gamma(\alpha)},\quad(*)\\
&=1
 \end{align} 
$(*)$ from the [definition of the $\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) for $\,\alpha>0,\;\beta>0$.

Comment: woah...i never would have thought to do that.

Comment: @O.rka: Well as indicated by Gregory Grant this had the form $\;\displaystyle \int_0^\infty x^{a}e^{-b/x}dx\;$ looking like a $\Gamma$ function except for the $\dfrac bx$ term so... Fine continuation,